# How to get previous row with condition in a DataFrame of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Each record(name) has date and status(begin/processing/finished). How to get the date of **Begin** status for each row? Thank you.

```
         date     name      status
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished
```

<s>I need this:</s>

```
         date     name      status  begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin  2020-10-04
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-02
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished  2020-10-02
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing  2020-10-04
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished  2020-10-04
```

#### Edited

Sorry, I did not mention that the Names can restart it's status. For example, **name_01** will appear "**Begin**" status again. See 9 and 10

Like this

```
         date     name      status  begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin  2020-10-04
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-02
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished  2020-10-02
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing  2020-10-04
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished  2020-10-04
9  2020-10-10  name_01       Begin  2020-10-10
10 2020-10-11  name_01  Processing  2020-10-10
```

Therefore, it is not just to find the only one "Begin" row of same name. The date of the latest record of "Begin" status of same name should have to be found.

Sorry for my poor English expression.

---

### Update:

Sample Data

```
         date     name      status
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing
3  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing
4  2020-10-06  name_03       Begin
5  2020-10-07  name_01    Finished
6  2020-10-08  name_02    Finished
7  2020-10-09  name_03  Processing
8  2020-10-10  name_03    Finished
9  2020-10-11  name_01       Begin
10 2020-10-12  name_01  Processing
11 2020-10-13  name_02       Begin
12 2020-10-14  name_02  Processing
13 2020-10-15  name_02    Finished
14 2020-10-16  name_01    Finished
```

Expect effect

```
         date     name      status  begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-01
4  2020-10-06  name_03       Begin  2020-10-06
5  2020-10-07  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-08  name_02    Finished  2020-10-05
7  2020-10-09  name_03  Processing  2020-10-06
8  2020-10-10  name_03    Finished  2020-10-06
9  2020-10-11  name_01       Begin  2020-10-11
10 2020-10-12  name_01  Processing  2020-10-11
11 2020-10-13  name_02       Begin  2020-10-13
12 2020-10-14  name_02  Processing  2020-10-13
13 2020-10-15  name_02    Finished  2020-10-13
14 2020-10-16  name_01    Finished  2020-10-11
```

I tried to run the code

```
df['begin_at'] = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda grp:
    grp.groupby((grp.status == 'Begin').cumsum(), as_index=False)
    .date.transform('first'))
```

but it gave

```
         date     name      status   begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin 2020-10-11
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin 2020-10-13
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing 2020-10-11
3  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing 2020-10-13
4  2020-10-06  name_03       Begin        NaT
5  2020-10-07  name_01    Finished 2020-10-11
6  2020-10-08  name_02    Finished 2020-10-13
7  2020-10-09  name_03  Processing        NaT
8  2020-10-10  name_03    Finished        NaT
9  2020-10-11  name_01       Begin        NaT
10 2020-10-12  name_01  Processing        NaT
11 2020-10-13  name_02       Begin        NaT
12 2020-10-14  name_02  Processing        NaT
13 2020-10-15  name_02    Finished        NaT
14 2020-10-16  name_01    Finished        NaT
```

Here is the whole code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["2020-10-01", "name_01", "Begin"],
    ["2020-10-02", "name_02", "Begin"],
    ["2020-10-03", "name_01", "Processing"],
    ["2020-10-05", "name_02", "Processing"],
    ["2020-10-06", "name_03", "Begin"],
    ["2020-10-07", "name_01", "Finished"],
    ["2020-10-08", "name_02", "Finished"],
    ["2020-10-09", "name_03", "Processing"],
    ["2020-10-10", "name_03", "Finished"],
    ["2020-10-11", "name_01", "Begin"],
    ["2020-10-12", "name_01", "Processing"],
    ["2020-10-13", "name_02", "Begin"],
    ["2020-10-14", "name_02", "Processing"],
    ["2020-10-15", "name_02", "Finished"],
    ["2020-10-16", "name_01", "Finished"],
], columns=["date", "name", "status"])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.sort_values(by="date")

print(df)

df['begin_at'] = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda grp:
                                          grp.groupby(
                                              (grp.status == 'Begin').cumsum(), as_index=False)
                                          .date.transform('first'))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an auxiliary *Series*:

```
begin_at = df[df.status == 'Begin'].set_index('name').date.rename('begin_at')
```

Then join your DataFrame with it:

```
result = df.join(begin_at, on='name')
```

The result is:

```
         date     name      status    begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin  2020-10-04
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-02
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished  2020-10-02
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing  2020-10-04
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished  2020-10-04
```

Or, if you don't need the original DataFrame any more, save the result
back under *df*.

## Edit

Your post contained only a **single** cycle of *Begin*, *Processing*
and *Finished* events for the same *name*.
But if there are **multiple** such cycles (at least for one *name*),
a different approach is needed:

```
df['begin_at'] = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda grp: grp.groupby(
    (grp.status == 'Begin').cumsum()).date.transform('first'))\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

It consists a two-level grouping.

- first level - by *name*,
- second level - by each "group" starting from *Begin* status.

Then, within each second-level group, for all member rows the first
*date* is generated.

An additional step is to drop the top level of MultiIndex, added by
grouping. Initially I attempted to avoid this additional index level
by passing *as_index=False*, but apparently sometimes this arrangement
fails.

And the whole result is saved under the new column.

## Edit 2

I have found a shorter and sipler solution.

1. Create an auxiliary *Series* with begin dates only:

   ```
   begin_at = df[df.status == 'Begin'].set_index('name').date.rename('begin_at')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
   name
   name_01   2020-10-01
   name_02   2020-10-02
   name_03   2020-10-06
   name_01   2020-10-11
   name_02   2020-10-13
   Name: begin_at, dtype: datetime64[ns]
   ```
2. Then merge ("asof" version):

   ```
   result = pd.merge_asof(df, begin_at, by='name', left_on='date', right_on='begin_at')
   ```

   This operation is actually broken down into 2 steps:

   - First rows of *df* and elements of *begin_at* are matched by *name*.
   - Then the actual *merge* is performed, in the default (*backwards*)
     direction, so for each row from *df* there is a lookup for equal or
     nearest earlier date in *begin_at*, from the "current group" of
     elements, with the matching value of *name* (the index).

Using *%timeit* check the execution time of each variant, on some bigger
source data sample. I suppose that the last variant will run faster
than my earlier variants.

Comment: How about the Names can restart it's status. For example, name_01 will appear "Begin" status again after the last "Finished". 
`9  2020-10-10  name_01    Begin`
`10  2020-10-11  name_01    Processing`

Comment: I tried your updated code for multiple cycles for same name. It does not work.

Comment: What is the problem? Add to your pose some example data with multiple cycles.

Comment: I update the main post please check it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I discovered the source of problem. Actually, I don't know why my first version failed, but at least I managed to work out a properly working solution. Compare with the previous version, which you included in your post.

Comment: I also tried your first version by using join. It does't work. The rows are duplicated with all Begin date.

However, using a loop to find the previous Begin status by filtering name and date is a possible solution for this. But it not Pandas style and it gives poor perforamnce with large dataset. Do you think it is possible to solve it by using simple data manipulation functions of Pandas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of alphabetical order of `begin`, `processing`, `finished`, Use `sort_values` and groupby `transform` `first`

```
df['begin_at'] = df.sort_values('status').groupby('name').date.transform('first')

Out[719]:
         date     name      status    begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin  2020-10-04
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-02
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished  2020-10-02
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing  2020-10-04
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished  2020-10-04
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `Begin` date is always <= `Processing` or `Finished`:

```py
>>> df.assign(begin_at=df.groupby('name').date.transform(min))
         date     name      status    begin_at
0  2020-10-01  name_01       Begin  2020-10-01
1  2020-10-02  name_02       Begin  2020-10-02
2  2020-10-03  name_01  Processing  2020-10-01
3  2020-10-04  name_03       Begin  2020-10-04
4  2020-10-05  name_02  Processing  2020-10-02
5  2020-10-06  name_01    Finished  2020-10-01
6  2020-10-07  name_02    Finished  2020-10-02
7  2020-10-08  name_03  Processing  2020-10-04
8  2020-10-09  name_03    Finished  2020-10-04
```